# Passing piped commands via SSH

Tags: powershell, ssh, pipe

I'm using the Powershell module [Posh-SSH](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-SSH/1.7.7) to ssh into an Ubuntu server and run commands. I'm not having any difficulty passing simple lines such as:

```
$sshSession = New-SSHSession -ComputerName server001 -Credential $credential
$sshStream = New-SSHShellStream -Index $sshSession.sessionID
$sshStream.WriteLine("history")
$sshStream.Read()
```

The last line outputs exactly what it's supposed to. I want to run the following on the server:

```
for guest in `nova list --all-tenants --host serverName | grep Shutdown | awk '{ print $2 }'`; do nova start $guest; sleep 5; done"
```

Pasting this line right into `$sshStream.WriteLine("")` doesn't work at all as ` is an escape character in Powershell and $'s are used for variables already. I attempted to work around this by escaping some characters and putting it into a variable:

```
$block = "for guest in ``nova list --all-tenants --host server001 | grep Shutdown | awk '{ print `$2 }'`; do nova start `$guest; sleep 5; done"
$sshStream.WriteLine("$block")
$sshStream.WriteLine($block)
```

Both of my attempts above do not get read properly on the server. Any idea how I can work around this or if there's a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a single quoted string, they don't do variable interpolation and backtick escapes.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Since there are single-quotes within the line of code I want passed `awk '{ print $2 }'`, this doesn't work properly

Comment: Then escape those. `' .. awk ''{print $w }'' .. '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TessellatingHeckler suggested, I used single-quotes and it worked:

```
$block = 'for guest in `nova list --all-tenants | grep Shutdown | awk ''{ print $2 }''`; do nova stop $guest; done'
$sshStream.WriteLine($block)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$block = @"
for guest in ``nova list --all-tenants --host server001 | grep Shutdown | awk '{ print `$2 }'`; do nova start `$guest; sleep 5; done
"@

$sshStream.WriteLine($block)
```

It will treat the "block" as a literal string (i.e. no escaping).

Comment: Just tried this exactly as you wrote it. Same problem as before, it gets read improperly and the last line of `$sshStream.Read()` is `>` as if I am continuing to write a multi-line command

Comment: @ImagineThat Can you try adding an additional carraige return in the code i.e. before the closing `"@`?